# Is there an XCode keyboard shortcut to go directly to the Search in Documentation Window

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

I often want to look up items in the documentation that are **not** in my code.  Is there a shorter way than pasting a string into the code somewhere, then double-tapping to select and Find Text in Documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes hold option, it turns to crosshairs, doubleclick a string in your code.

For UIView it would open up the following window, you can click on the little door to go directly to the documentation:

[image]

Comment: @Nick, thanks.  That's a trick I didn't know.  However, I'm trying to skip the step of pasting a string into my code in the first place.  I'm trying to search for things that are NOT in my code (yet).

Comment: You mean opening up the documentation itself? Do you want to skip the typing?

Comment: I think I found it: Option-Command-Shift-?      This is for the case when I see a new function or method or class name on SO and I want to read about it, so it's not in my code already.  But I'll give you the up-vote for the cross-hair trick. Thanks.

Comment: Ah you wanted the shortcut to open the documentation directly :) I wasn't sure where you've been heading.

Comment: I'm often not sure of that myself.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it possible to modify the size of that text by any means?